# How do I remove imperfections caused by the subdivision surfaces modifier?

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I have run into imperfections with the mesh using the subdivision surfaces modifier before, but they were usually caused by either doubles or edges that penetrate the mesh. I tried removing doubles at a merge distance of 0.010, I tried degenerate dissolve and limited dissolve ruined my mesh. I also tried the recalculate outside method. I've looked around online, but other people's imperfections were caused by things I had already tried to solve, which weren't the causes of my mesh's imperfections.

How do I remove the imperfections near the eyes, including the creases and darker areas?
[image]

So everyone can try things out and see if their solution solves the problem, here is a link to the file I'm using:

http://www.filedropper.com/ambiguoussave11

Thank you very much for any help. :)

*Knowing your problems may one day be resolved, it fills you with determination.*

Comment: To correctly remove them search the topic "face topology" and adjust your mesh accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

The imperfections in your model are mostly caused by faces with more than 4 sides (n-gons).
For an optimal subdivision surface calulation, you should try to use only 4-sided faces (quads). Triangles may look strange in some situations, but n-gons are smoothed pretty unpredictable.

You can find all n-gons in your mesh by selecting a quad, pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>, choosing `Polygon Sides` and changing the `Compare` setting to `Greater`. Keep in mind that the first quad is still selected.

[image: Faces selected after Shift+G]
You can see that these are exactly in the most problematic areas.

In order to create quads from n-gons, split them using the knife tool (<kbd>K</kbd>). You can combine triangles by pressing <kbd>X</kbd> and coosing `Dissolve Edges`.

I also added a few edge loops to get this result:

[image: Wireframe after retopology]

Answer (score 0):

before the "subdivision" modifier, try a "remesh" modifier (mode: smooth; octree: maybe 8; unselect remove disconnected faces). Then do a "decimate" modifier to a better/smaller poly count. Then do the "subdivision".